# MYSQL single query to get COUNT(DISTINCT columnName) with group by and order by

Tags: java, mysql

I have an entity class

```
public class TeklaEventE {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer projectId;
    private Integer drawingId;
    private Integer userId;
    private String eventType;
    private LocalDateTime eventDate; 
    private LocalDateTime modifiedDate; 
    private String projectName;
    private String userName;
    private transient int noOfUser;    
    // getter setter
}
```

I want to get `* , COUNT(DISTINCT userId)` by grouping `projectId` by ordering `eventDate`

I tried following queries

1. `SELECT *,COUNT(DISTINCT userId) as noOfUser FROM teklaevent group by projectId order by eventDate desc;`
   it gives correct count but it first run `group by` then `order by` but i need latest row who has distinct `projectId`. Then i try second query as suggested
2. `select * FROM TeklaEvent where id in (select max(id) FROM TeklaEvent group by projectId) order by eventDate desc;` It gives perfect row what I need because `eventDate` is always current date. But as I try to get `COUNT(DISTINCT userId)` from below query.
3. `select *,COUNT(DISTINCT userId) as noOfUser FROM TeklaEvent where id in (select max(id) FROM TeklaEvent group by projectId) order by eventDate desc;` it fails to give me correct result.

How to do this in a single query?

Comment: You can't do `SELECT *` when using `GROUP BY`. It makes no sense, so re-think what you're trying to do. Reason: `GROUP BY projectId` means to only return one row for each distinct `projectId` value, but since there can be many rows in the table with the same `projectId` value, which of the many values for e.g. `drawingId` should be returned?

Comment: I believe the third option uses GROUP BY correctly. Maybe ORDER BY eventDate desc just needs to move into the subquery?

Comment: Oh but the count distinct makes no sense, the count distinct needs to be inside the subquery, and you probably need to join on the subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
select a.*, t.noOfUser
from teklaevent a
inner join (
  select max(id) maxid, count(distinct userId) noOfUser
  from  teklaevent
  group by projectId
) t on a.id = t.maxid;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join on a subselect for the count

```
select a.*, t.noOfUser 
from  teklaevent
inner join (

  select projectId , count(distinct userId) noOfUser
  from  teklaevent
  group by projectId
) t a.projectId = t.projectId
```

Comment: this is Not working.. `select a.*, t.noOfUser
from  teklaevent a
inner join (
  select projectId , count(distinct userId) noOfUser
  from  teklaevent
  group by projectId
) t on a.projectId = t.projectId;` It return all rows

Comment: This work `select a.*, t.noOfUser
from  teklaevent a
inner join (
  select max(id) maxid, count(distinct userId) noOfUser
  from  teklaevent
  group by projectId
) t on a.id = t.maxid;`